# How to create a typewriter effect in JavaScript THAT will take into account html tag rules?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I had some text from a div tag like this:

```
 <div id="outPutContainer">
     <div id="contentDiv" style="display:none;"> This is some cool content... </div>
 </div>
```

Now if I wanted to, I could create a JavaScript function that will print the characters one at a time and it will work just fine.  Example below.

```
function printSentence(inner, outer, index, speed) {
    var input = document.getElementById(inner).innerHTML;
    var timer = setInterval(function(){
        document.getElementById(outer).innerHTML+=input.charAt(index);
        index++;
        if(index  == sentence.length -1){
            printResume(inner, outer, index+1, speed);
        }else{
           clearInterval(timer);
        }
     }, speed);
}

printSentence("contentDiv", "outPutContainer", 0, 100);
```

Again, the above function works just fine, however let's say I wanted to take into account html tags within the element, how would that work.  An example would be

```
<div id="contentDiv2"> This is some cool <strong>content</strong>
    <p>Paragraph of content</p>
</div>
```

So the ideal effect would be

This is some cool **content**

Paragraph of content

(The typewriter effect was inspired by Charlie)  "I like to give credit where credit is due"  (:
[Javascript typing effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912375/javascript-typing-effect)

I suppose I can throw in a jsFiddle to make easier on folks.
http://jsfiddle.net/bJxe3/19/

Comment: Consider creating recursive method based on your which will work with nested elements, so it's good start, just extend this code to parse children and check every for type, if it's just a text use your prentSequence somthing like this :-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of adding a character at a time, you could update the content with a substring of the string up to the index.  If the character at the index is a less-than sign (<), simply skip ahead to the next greater-than sign (>).

**Snippet:**

```js
const printSentence = (id, sentence, speed = 50) => {
  let index = 0;
  let element = document.getElementById(id);
  
  let timer = setInterval(function() {
    const char = sentence[index];
    
    if (char === '<') {
      index = sentence.indexOf('>', index);  // skip to greater-than
    }
    
    element.innerHTML = sentence.slice(0, index);
    
    if (++index === sentence.length) {
      clearInterval(timer);
    }
  }, speed);
} // printSentence

printSentence(
  'contentDiv',
  'This is some cool <strong>content</strong>.<p>Paragraph of content</p><ul><li>This<li>is<li>a<li>test</ul><table><tr><th>Header 1<th>Header 2<tr><td>Row 2, Col 1<td>Row 2, Col 2</table>',
  50
);
```

```css
body, table {font: 12px verdana;}
table {border-spacing: 0;}
td,th {border: 1px solid gray;}
th {background: #def;}
```

```html
<div id="contentDiv"></div>
```

Comment: Simple but effective.

Comment: Interesting Rick.  This is great solution if I wanted to supply my content within my JavaScript, I wonder how I could have the JS read the tags if they were in my HTML?  Either way, this works, thanks

Comment: You could pass the innerHTML to the function instead of a string constant.  Glad this helps.

Comment: I- I'm speechless.

Comment: This is an amazing answer

Comment: Like every other comment, I'm amazed by the simplicity and effectiveness of the solution, many thanks.