# How to get words from list and display them char by char with time delay

Tags: javascript

I want to simulate an autocomplete function. A sentence should be completed with words from a list. These words should be displayed char by char at the end of the sentence.

This is the HTML:

```
<p>We can help you with<span id="complete"></span></p>
```

This is part of the JS:

```
let words = ["design", "frontend", "backend"];
let output = document.getElementById("complete");
```

First I tried this:

```
words.forEach((e) => {
  for (i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(e[i]);
    }, 500);
  }
});
```

console logged:

[image]

I **think** it is because the iterator steps forward **before** the setTimeout.

So I tried a while loop like this:

```
words.forEach((e) => {
  let i = 0;
  while (i <= e.length) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(e[i]);
    }, 600);
    i++;
  }
});
```

I got this:

[image]

**I have no idea how to place character by character – so that they add up to the word like: d; de; des; desi; desig; design with kind of a delay between each character.**

(To place the words char by char in the DOM, I would not use console log, but complete.innerHTML += variableForWordinList[index for char])

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a typewriter effect in JavaScript THAT will take into account html tag rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29462305/how-to-create-a-typewriter-effect-in-javascript-that-will-take-into-account-html)

Comment: Change `e[i]` to `e`

Comment: Take a look here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/typewriter-effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` is asynchronous. So by the time it executes the function, the value you are logging has already changed.
What are you trying to achieve is a sort of typewriter Effect. It can be achieved using a combo of `setInterval` and `setTimeout`.

```js
let words = ["design", "frontend", "backend"];
let output = document.getElementById("complete");

let idx = 0;
let str = "";

function typeWrite() {
  if (idx >= words.length) idx = 0;

  let word = words[idx];
  let charInd = 0;
  let interval = setInterval(() => {
    if (charInd >= word.length) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      setTimeout(() => {
        idx++;
        str = "";
        typeWrite();
      }, 1000);  // <- Wait for 1 sec before printing next word
    }
    str += word.charAt(charInd);
    output.innerHTML = str;
    charInd++;
  }, 100); // <- Delay between each character
}

typeWrite();
```

```html
<p>We can help you with <span id="complete"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

> I think it is because the iterator steps forward before the setTimeout.

If you add a `console.log(i)` to the loop, you'll see unexpected value, so your assumptions seems about right.

---

Since probably want to show the 3 words after each other, not combined, we'll need another way to 'wait' after the first word has been 'typed'

There are many libraries out there, like [TypewriterJs](https://github.com/tameemsafi/typewriterjs) or one of [jQuery's plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13325008/typewriter-effect-with-jquery), but for sake of learning, let's try to make one ourself.

```js
let words = ["design", "frontend", "backend"];
let output = document.getElementById("complete");

const s = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

async function showWord(w) {
  output.innerHTML = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < w.length; i++) {
    await s(150);
    output.innerHTML += w[i];
  }
  await s(500);
}

words.reduce((c, w) =>
  c.then(showWord.bind(null, w))
, showWord(words.shift()));
```

```html
<p>We can help you with <span id="complete"></span></p>
```

---

The `s` function uses [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) to 'wait' for some milliseconds.

Then we define a [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function that will 'type' our word, and delay when needed.

Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) we can loop through the array of words, using `shift` to remove it from the array

Answer (score 0):

I use it for the case substring. Like that:

```js
words = ['Hello World'];

function showC(words) {
  let str = words.join()
  for(let i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {      
            setTimeout(() => {             
             console.log(str.substring(0, i));
         
        }, 500*i);    
  }
}
showC(words)
```

Comment: I check the last character is missing. i will updated soon ;-)

Comment: `i <= str.length`

Comment: @pistou Great! Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're expecting? :

```js
let words = ["design", "frontend", "backend"];
let output = document.getElementById("complete");

words.forEach((e, index) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < e.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(e[i]);
    }, 500 * i * index);
  }
});
```