# Simulate user writing in a textbox javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this form and I write into it using:

```
document.getElementById("val").value ="value";
```

This inserts the value automatically into the textbox.

Is it possible to insert it simulating user writing? So inserting a letter one by one and not all together?

Comment: you could use timer and write characters one by one... is that what you are trying to do?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_typewriter.asp

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912375/javascript-typing-effect

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript typing effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912375/javascript-typing-effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if this works for you. It will insert the character one by one with delay of around 300ms between each character.

```js
var word = "value";
var n = 0;
var x = document.getElementById("val");

(function loop() {
  x.value += word[n];
  if (++n < word.length) {
    setTimeout(loop, 300);
  }
})();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="val">
```

Comment: it says that sentences is not defined

Answer (score 3):

An example that allows an onset delay, interresponse-time between keystrokes, preservation of cursor position, as well as native change event triggers:

```js
let target = document.getElementById('testarea')
target.selectionStart = 30;
target.focus();

/**
 * simulateTextareaInput
 * @param id {string} The id of the textarea to target.
 * @param text {string} The text to input, character-by-character.
 * @param lat {number} The latency / time to wait before beginning input.
 * @param irt {number} The interresponse-time between each input / simulated keystroke.
 */
const sim = function (id, text, lat, irt) {
    const length = text.length-1;
    var current = 0;
    /**
     * insertText
     * @param str {string} The character to input into the text area
     */
    const insertChar = function(char) {
        // get element
        var target = document.getElementById(id);
        if (target !== null) { // if it is found in the dom ...
            let [start, end] = [target.selectionStart, target.selectionEnd];
            // insert char
            target.setRangeText(char, start, end, 'select');
            // move cursor forward 1
            target.selectionStart = start+1;
            // trigger any onChange listeners
            var event = new window.Event('change', { bubbles: true });
            target.dispatchEvent(event);
        } else {
            console.log(`No <textarea> with id "${id}" found.`)
        };
    };
    const write = function() {
        // insert current character
        insertChar(text[current]);
        if(current < length) { // so long as there are more chars to input
            current++; // increment
            setTimeout(function(){write()},irt); // recurisvely write next char
        };
    };
    setTimeout(function(){
        // kickoff input 
        setTimeout(function(){write()},irt)
    },lat); // wait this long before starting
};

sim('testarea','this text was simulated after 2s -- cool!',2000,50);
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- begin demo -->

<textarea id='testarea'>
hello world
simulated output: 
new text will appear on the above line
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on it:

```
function typeWriter(txt, element, speed, i=0) {
    if (i < txt.length) {
        document.getElementById(element).innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
        i++;
        setTimeout(function() {typeWriter(txt, element, speed, i);}, speed);
    }
}
```

`txt` - Text to write,

`element` - id of element (e.g `val`, without `#`),

`speed` - speed of writing in ms.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = document.getElementById("val");
input.select(); 

const textMessage = "The message that you want to display";
let currentIndex = 0;
const delay = 400;

const writeText = function() {
  input.value += textMessage[currentIndex];
  if (currentIndex < textMessage.length - 1) {
    currentIndex++;
    setTimeout(function() {
      writeText()
    }, delay * Math.random());
  } else {
    return
  }
}

writeText()
```

```html
<input id="val" type="text" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can simulate a user typing in an `input` field, by using the built-in `setInterval` method which repetitively calls a function after a delay.

Here's a demo:

> In the demo, I implemented a function that receives two arguments: the
>   first argument is the `input` element's `ID` and the second one is the
>   text that you want to be written in that field.
>
> The `setInterval` method's second argument is the delay(the time which
>   the callback function is called after) which you can change to suit
>   your needs.

```js
function simulateWriting(inputId, val) {
  var inp = document.getElementById(inputId),
  i = 0,
  l = val.length,
  intervalId = setInterval(function() {
    (i < l) ? inp.value += val[i++]:clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, 500);
}

// calling the function with input id=input-val and value='some value'.
simulateWriting('input-val', 'some value');
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input-val" />
```