# How to do this text animation

Tags: html, css, reactjs, angular, web

Please visit the following link provided https://replit.com/teams-for-education and you will see the moving text animation typed automatically and then cleared ...

Like this one:
[image]

.

How to do this text animation...
Any language would work... React/Angular/HTML+CSS anything

Please provide any github links or source code or anything else.

Comment: Actually I don't know what to search for this.

Comment: That's why I am asking that if any help is provided in any language, I'll just understand the algorithm/workflow of how this is implemented and then rewrite that to my preferred language.

Comment: You might have some luck [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912375/javascript-typing-effect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my Knock off:

```js
let i = 0,
  i2 = 0,
  custom = document.querySelector('#custom')

setInterval(write, 100)

function write() {
  text('I am Stephen!')
}

function text(str) {
  if (i < str.length) {
    custom.textContent += str[i++]
  } else if (i < str.length * 2) {
    i++
  } else if (i2 < str.length) {
    custom.textContent = str.substring(0, str.length - i2 - 1)
    i2++
  } else if (i >= str.length * 2 - 1) {
    i = 0
    i2 = 0
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 90vh;
}

:is(#a, #b) {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 4px 1px;
  top: 0;
}

#a {
  border-right: 3px solid #fa4;
  margin-right: .5ch;
}

:is(#a, #b)::after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

#a::after {
  content: 'start';
  background: #fA4;
  transform: translate(3px, calc(-1em - 3px));
}

#b::after {
  content: 'end';
  background: #4af;
  transform: translate( calc(4ch - .5px), calc(-1em - 3px));
}

#b {
  border-right: 3px solid #4af;
}
```

```html
<div><span id=b><span id=a>Hello, </span><span id=custom></span></span>
</div>
```

It is not as clean but I think I got the concept you needed.

Comment: Very impressive!