# How could I make an infinite loop to show items from an array letter by letter?

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop

I want to make an infinite loop to show msg letter by letter and item by item from an array. Can anyone help ??

```js
let textArr = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
let i = 0;
let j = 0;

function spell() {

  if (j = 0) {
    clear();
  }

  setTimeout(function() {
    show();
    j + 0;
    if (j = textArr[i].length) {
      j = 0;
      i++;
    }
    if (i = textArr.length) {
      i = 0;
      j = 0;
    }
    spell();
  }, 1000);

}

// clear the spelling
function clear() {
  document.querySelector('#targ').innerHTML = '';
}

// show the spelling
function show() {
  document.querySelector('#targ').innerHTML += textArr[i][j];
}

addEventListener('load', spell());
```

```html
<center id="targ">
  </centre>
```

Comment: what should be your expected result?

Comment: You want to write `first`, `second`, `third` letter by letter indefinitely (keep looping forever)?

Comment: use the ModuloOperator sth like    i%textArr.length

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript typing effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912375/javascript-typing-effect)

Answer (score 0):

[`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) your array into a string, and iterate through that.

```js
const arr = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
const targ = document.querySelector('#targ');

// Pass the array into the function
function spell(arr) {

  // `join` it up
  const str = arr.join(' ');

  // Have an inner function that you call
  // from the setTimeout initialising the index to 0
  function loop(i = 0) {

    // If the index is less than the string length
    // update the textContent of the element, and
    // increase the index
    if (i < str.length) {
      targ.textContent += str[i];
      ++i;

    // Otherwise empty the textContent,
    // and set the index to zero
    } else {
      targ.textContent = '';
      i = 0;
    }

    // Then call the loop function again with
    // the updated index as an argument
    setTimeout(loop, 200, i);
  }
  
  loop();

}

spell(arr);
```

```html
<div id="targ"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let textarr = ['first', 'second', 'third'];
let i = 0
let j = 0
let str = textarr[0]
setInterval(function() {
    i += 1
    console.log( str.slice(0,i))
    if(i == textarr[j%3].length){
    i = 0
    j += 1
    str = textarr[j%3]
    }
  }, 1000);
```