# Writing animation is removing HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with an animation that I am trying to insert into my website.

I have written the following JavaScript. Basically what it does is append a letter every few seconds.

```
function typeText(element, elementText, index = 0) {
  if (index < elementText.length) {
    element.textContent += elementText.charAt(index);
    index++;
    const typingSpeed = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 30;
    setTimeout(() => typeText(element, elementText, index), typingSpeed);
  }
}
```

It works fine until I have an html tag nested inside another html tag. Something like this:

```
<h2> Some text <span class="blue-text"> some more text </span>  </h2>
```

What happens is that "some text" is written correctly but when the span is about to be written, the typewriter slows down for a few seconds and deletes the span tag with all the associated styles and then writes the rest of the text.

What I need is for the function to preserve the HTML. I don't know how to solve it and a CSS approach will not work because the way of doing a writing animation is not responsive.

Comment: Your solution is not going to wok with HTML tags in the text. With HTML, the solution is going to be a lot more work. Unclear how textConent is causing issues since it is not writing out html.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript typing effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19912375/javascript-typing-effect)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would be a better idea to make a CSS animation rather than writing the code for the animation in js.

here's an example of a CSS animation

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #div{
            position: absolute;
            animation: anim 3s infinite linear;
            background-color: black;
            width: 300px;
            height: 300px;
        }
        @keyframes anim {
            0%{left: 0%;}
            100%{left: 80%;} 
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="div"></div>
</body>
```